# Para añadir un método al "prototype" de mi función constructora, siempre tiene que ser a través de una función expresada?

Tags: javascript

He tratado de crear la función que quiero introducir en el prototype aparte y luego añadirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function Animal(nombre, genero) {
  this.nombre = nombre;   //Esto es mi función constructora.
  this.genero = genero;
}

function Sonar2 () {
  console.log(`estoy haciendo ruido, soy ${this.nombre}`)
}

Animal.prototype.sonar2 = Sonar2(); 

const doky = new Animal("doky", "Macho");
doky.sonar2();
```

"Error": Undefined.

Comment: buenas! te recomiendo pasar el código en imagen a texto y agregar los errores que estas teniendo (el detalle) para que la pregunta quede más completa :)

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los consejos de las persona que me comentaron. De todas formas, luego de un par de horas di con la solución. Dejaré igualmente el post por si a alguien le recorta tiempo en un futuro.

**Solución:**

Al colocar el método con los paréntesis, se almacenaba el valor devuelto en la propiedad "prototype". Al ser una función que no devuelve un valor se almacenaba "undefined". Esto lo resolví quitándole los paréntesis, de esta manera se guardaba la función sin ejecutarse y obviamente sin guardar el valor devuelto :). Código:

```
Animal.protoype.sonar2 = Sonar2;
```